# How to do integ test using mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have following two methods which i want to test

```
public class Orders {
    private final LambdaLogger logger;
    private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    public Orders(LambdaLogger logger, AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB){
        this.logger = logger;
        this.dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
    }

    public List<Orders> getOrders(){
        logger.log("getting all orders");

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withProjectionExpression("OrderId");
        logger.log("Expression created");

        PaginatedScanList<Orders> scan = dynamoDBMapper.scan(Orders.class, scanExpression);

        return scan.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Now, I want to do testing using Mockito for this class. There are couple of things that I am confuse (or unable to get working).

First, `DynamoDBMapper` is being created using `amazonDynamoDBClient`. So if in my class i `Mock` `AmazonDynamoDB`, how the `dynamoDBMapper` would get created?

How would I test that my function is actually setting projection right?

How would i test on paginatedScanList?

Comment: "So if in my class i Mock AmazonDynamoDB, how the dynamoDBMapper would get created?" the same way it's created when you don't mock AmazonDynamoDB

Comment: can you change that impl(construction) or you have to stick with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is violation of [Dependency Injection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that does not allow you to create a unit test.

Orders should not create any objects it should receive them as dependencies through constructor or setter methods. E.g. you could pass DynamoDBScanExpressionFactory and DynamoDBMapper to Orders' constructor. Then you would be able to mock them with mockito.

Comment: Yup, thats what i ended up doing. We didnt have dependency injection setup as of now, so didn't know if this would be correct path to move forward or not. Thanks for help though.